# VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04 - vboxclient the virtualbox kernel service is not running

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I've installed VirtualBox (with Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop) and Guest Additions on my Windows 7 machine.

Every time it boots up I get the following error message which goes away:

```
vboxclient the virtualbox kernel service is not running. exiting.
```

How can I disable this message? I've tried the following:

I deleted `/etc/xdg/autostart/vboxclient.desktop` file.

But I am still seeing the message when logging in.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Popup during boot up initializations: "VBoxClient: the VirtualBox kernel service is not running. Exiting"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656744/popup-during-boot-up-initializations-vboxclient-the-virtualbox-kernel-service)

Comment: @oneself Clearly the two questions are duplicates, but the direction of the duplication should be reversed and this question should be left open.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try eject the VBOXADDITIONS cd image on ubuntu and "insert" it again from Vbox menu. I was just having this same problem and doing this fixed it.

Answer (score 30):

This usually happens when you update the Guest's Linux Kernel.
After each update, you need to do:

- For Host (**installing server**)

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
  ```
- For Guest (**installing additions**)

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup
  ```

The reason why inserting the VBox addition disk again works is because that's one of the things the installation procedure does as well.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the problem for me. Guest Ubuntu updated and then this error was showing. Running the guest command fixed it.

Comment: On Mac OSX El Capitan the host command doesn't work, but reinstalling the cd image and running the guest command does.

Comment: I'm getting `sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxadd: command not found`

Comment: Great! It was enough to execute setup on Guest side for me.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye, had the same issue, reinstalling Linux Additions helped me get rid of the error `vboxclient the virtualbox kernel service is not running`. Follow instructions here  https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-linux Do not forget to reboot the VM.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 on Virtualbox 5.02. The same notification went away after I selected two "restricted drivers" from Virtualbox.

More specifically, from **Software & Updates > Additional Drivers** tab, there are two drivers previously not selected: **Using x86 virtualization solution - X11 guest utilities from virtualbox-guest-x11** and **Using x86 virtualization solution - guest addition module source for dkms from virtualbox-guest-dkms**. The notification was gone after I selected to use these two proprietary drivers.

Update: one of these two drivers seem to cause a repository inconsistency when I run `apt-get update`. I chose to `use the package maintainer's version` to solve the inconsistency, and haven't run into any further problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to prevent this warning from showing when you boot up your system, follow the description [here](https://forum.antergos.com/topic/3568/tired-of-error-vboxclient-the-virtualbox-kernel-service-is-not-running): Look for the file `98vboxadd-xclient` (e.g. `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/98vboxadd-xclient`) and comment out line 26 giving the warning as shown below:

```bsh
if ! test -c /dev/vboxguest 2>/dev/null; then
   # Do not start if the kernel module is not present.
   # notify-send "VBoxClient: the VirtualBox kernel service is not running.  Exiting."
```

(Works on Ubuntu 16.04.)

Comment: On my 14.04 machine the `if` block is followed by an `elif` block. If I comment out line 26, which is everything that's contained in the `if` block, this will be seen as a syntax error and I can't log in any longer. 
Quick fix: add a meaningless line of code instead of the one commented out (e.g. `echo woof > /dev/null`)

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the **purge** command which deletes configuration files

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

I've found it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656744/popup-during-boot-up-initializations-vboxclient-the-virtualbox-kernel-service)