# Linux VM error: VirtualBox kernel service is not running after installing Virtual Box Guest Additions

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu on VirtualBox today.
In order to have a shared folder with my host OS (Win 7) I followed the advise listed here:

[Shared_Folder](https://askubuntu.com/a/679916/759791)

When I start the VM now I get :

```
VBoxClient: the VirtualBox kernel service is not running. Exiting
```

at the top of the screen and I am unable to change the screen size to the full resolution of my Monitor. This was possible before. 
I already tried the solution supplied here:

[Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642991/virtualbox-ubuntu-14-04-vboxclient-the-virtualbox-kernel-service-is-not-runnin)

But it does not work. My virtual box installation is not updated to the current version for various reasons.

Comment: The solution that you link mentions the need to install the vbox addons and run sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup on your guest, were you able to sucesfully install the addons and run the command ?

Comment: No it says: `sudo: vboxadd: command not found`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm although this is how I personally install them https://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I more or less did this i guess as i followed this rutine: [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/693360/759791) i am confused because now the mashine even cant chosse the right resolution of my screen . It is stuck with the basic 3 standard choices.

Comment: If you ran the .run file reboot. easier than manually loading the modules.

Comment: i tried to reboot a few times... but it did not change anything. or do i need to reboot the Host? i did not use the .run file i mounted the guest edition from the devices menue and followed the on screen promt.

Comment: Open a terminal, install the dependencies, and run the .run file manually, then reboot. the commands are here - https://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68701/discussion-between-panther-and-norrinradd).

Comment: I could not login as user `ubuntu` .The  `sudo sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` command was not possible. furthermore my location where the disc appears is `/media/osboxes/VBOXADDITIONS_5.0.12_103815`. If i click Run software when the VBOXADDITIONS is open in the filebrowser it delivers a promt that an xserver is missing... unfortunately i was not fast enough to read it

Comment: Fruthermore after restart it tells me to See 'systemctl status vboxadd.service' for details after reboot?